# Postgres Docker image is not creating database with custom name

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

The documentation of the `postgres` Docker image [says](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/#postgres_db) the following about the env var `POSTGRES_DB`:

> This optional environment variable can be used to define a different name for the default database that is created when the image is first started. If it is not specified, then the value of POSTGRES_USER will be used.

I have found that this is not true at all. For example, with this config:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:11.3-alpine
    restart: always
    container_name: store
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=custom
      - POSTGRES_DB=customname
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD_FILE=/run/secrets/db_password
    secrets:
      - db_password

volumes:
  postgres_data:

secrets:
  db_password:
    file: config/.secrets.db_password
```

The default database is called `postgres`, and not `customname` as I have specified:

```
$ docker exec -it store psql -U custom customname
psql: FATAL:  database customname does not exist
$ docker exec -it store psql -U custom postgres
psql (11.3)
Type help for help.

postgres=# ^D
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Providing the environment variables, as you did, SHOULD create the `customname` database when the container is initialized. There is no need to create the username and database in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/`' init scripts.

I would make sure there isn't any hanging `postgres_data` volume. If you have previously started the container without specifing the environment variables, the volume gets created for the default `postgres` database. Next time you start the container (with the `POSTGRES_DB` env specified), the database creation part is skipped.

Just to make sure, remove any created volume (the name should be something like `*_postgres_data`)

```
docker volume ls
docker volume rm <volume_name>
```

See [User and DB were not created from environment variable arguments](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/453#issuecomment-393939412) as well. Hope that helps

Comment: Wow, you nailed it! I did so much searching but I had not found that issue. Finally everything is clear.

Comment: When I run `docker volume ls`, it gives me a long list of volumes, all of which described by something looking like a hash, I don't see any `postgres_data`. Did the format change or does this mean that I don't have any such volumes?

Comment: @cgold `postgres_data` is the name of the volume declared in the `docker_compose` file in question. In your case, the hashed volumes names returned by the `ls` command are anonymous volumes. PostgreSQL `Dockerfile` defines a volume for `/var/lib/postgresql/data` where the database data is stored. If this volume is not mapped explicitly to the host, an anonymous volume is created. Use `docker inspect -f '{{ .Mounts }}' container-id` to see the mapping

Comment: `docker volume ls` returns a blank list to me. I deleted the host volume before starting the container again, but it still created the default database but not the custom one.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the database first.

If you want to do that automatically for new data directories, then the official Docker Postgres image has an option to do so by placing [Initialization Scripts](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres/#initialization-scripts) with the extension `.sql` in the `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` directory.

For example, create a file with contents like:

```
CREATE USER custom_user;
CREATE DATABASE custom_db;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE custom_db TO custom_user;
```

And save it to `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-db.sql` in the container, e.g. with `COPY` in the `Dockerfile`.  Scripts with extension `.sql` inside that directory will only run if the DATA directory is empty, and multiple files will run in the alphabetical order of the file names.

If you want to set it up manually, you can also do that with the [createdb utility](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html)

```
createdb [connection-option...] [option...] [dbname [description]]
```

Or by connecting to the `postgres` database and use the `CREATE DATABASE ...` command, e.g.

```
docker exec -it store psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE DATABASE customname;'
```

If you connect interactively as in your question, you can do the following:

```
$ docker exec -it store psql -U postgres
psql (11.3)
Type help for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE customname;
CREATE DATABASE

postgres=# \c customname
```

The last command will connect you to the `customname` database.

Comment: The wording of the documentation made me think that the database would be created automatically. I need some way to create it during the compose pipeline though.

Comment: Actually I read the docs again and it says "the database that is created when the image is first started". So it definitely seems like it should create it automatically.

Comment: Did you previously create a cluster on that volume before you added that environment variable to docker-compose?  I don't think it will create a new database if the cluster already exists.

Comment: @rubik - OK, I understand better what you want to do now.  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you've changed the username/password since the very first run, try to delete the prior volume created

```
    docker volume rm <volume-name>
```

Then run the compose file again